# tf.layers.Dense doesn't work for tensorflow. How to use it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, debugging, keras, neural-network

I have a very simple few lines of code (I was following some tensorflow tutorial)
Specifications: Tensorflow v. = 1.15 ,
IDE = PyCharm

```
import tensorflow as tf 

network = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

network = tf.layers.Dense(network,10,activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

and when I try to run, it gives me

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'activation'
```

I've tried every "combination" for `tf.layers.Dense`. for example,

I've tried

```
network = tf.layers.Dense(inputs=network, units=10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

This doesn't recognize the argument "inputs", but the tutorial I'm seeing, clearly uses the first argument as the input, 2nd argument as the units, and third argument as the activation

Answer (score 0):

Few issues,

- Your placeholder doesn't have a shape (it's a scalar). `Dense` layer needs a 2+ dimensional input.
- You pass the input to the Dense layers as `Dense(args)(input)`.

So change the code to following and it'll work. You can change the shape argument according to the what the input dimensionality is for your problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf 

network = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 15])

network = tf.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.relu)(network)
```

Comment: hmmm. I thought one of the biggest advantage of using a placeholder was so you don't need to specify the shape of the input data. Is there a way to accept an arbitrary input size?

Comment: How would I then implement dropout or batchnorm after the relu? I tried tf.layers.dropout(network,0.5) and it doesn't work. I also tried tf.layers.dropout(0.5)(network) and it didn't work.

Comment: `network = tf.layers.Dropout(0.5)(network)` does work. What error did you get?

Comment: @KevinKim, regarding your first question, yes you can leave dimensions arbitrary by setting that dimension to `None`. But the problem is you cannot have all dimensions `None`, because Dense layer needs to know the input dimensionality.